# How do I tell my webpage to use a specific UI Culture?

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-3.5, cultureinfo

I can tell my page to use a certain `CultureInfo` like

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
```

The code above **only set's** the `CultureInfo`, not the `UICulture`, **how can I** tell the Page to **bypass what the browser says** and use a specific one, so all `GlobalResource`'s could be applied to the correct culture?

in the code above and having Swedish as my first browser language I get:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name --> sv-SE
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name --> en-US
```

I need to set the `CurrentUICulture` so all localization is made, in this case, in English and not Swedish, like browser is set to:

[image]
<sub>(source: [balexandre.com](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-09-22_1645.png))</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
```

I tried it in OnInit of my page and it loaded the resources properly.

**EDIT**:  or you could try setting it in the web.config as shown here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Comment: That's the current thread, if I'm using more than one thread to process stuff, I need to set it every time I create a new thread :o( was trying to get something in Page wide or Application wide (without using the web.config, maybe the global.asax)

Comment: you're right about that.  See my edit.  I found a good link on MSDN showing how you can set it in the web.config.

Comment: Steve, maybe you didn't read the comment well, I need **without** being in the web.config ! I know how easy is to set up the Page declaration, in Page and in Web.Config, but I want programmatically

Answer (score 1):

There's an example on the MSDN website that explains how to do this: [How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx)

Essentially you can set the `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` properties of the currently executing thread (see the article for the full code example, this is an extract):

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
```